# Android Studio test one file without compiling rest of project

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit

I just made a big change to a class. Many classes in my project use this class, but this class does not need any other classes, it could run by itself. It has no libraries, no references to other classes except for the java package.

Is there anyway I can run a Junit test on this class alone? When I try and run a test it compiles the project and I get a bunch of compile-time errors because I haven't finished integrating the changes, I just want to test this class before integrating. Is that possible?